# Add custom action in WiX after selecting Next button

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, wix3

I have a problem with my wix installer. I want to execute a custom action when clicking on the next button on a custom page 'InputDlg'. Thats working fine so far. But I also need a return value. If the CustomAction returns `ActionResult.Success` the installer should proceed to next page (this is working). But if the CA fails I want to stay on the current page 'InputDlg'. The installer should NOT proceed or exit the setup. Is this somehow possible?

```
    <CustomAction Id="SendRequestCa"
                BinaryKey="CustomActions"
                Execute="immediate"
                DllEntry="SendHttpRequest"
                Return="check"/>

    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next" >
            <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SendRequestCa">1</Publish>         
    </Control>
```